# toggle() causes <audio> to stop

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I have a `div` which contains an `audio` tag:

```html
<div>
    <audio controls autoload preload></audio>
</div>
```

I use the following code to show/hide that div with jQuery:

```
div.toggle("slide", { direction: "down" });
```

When I trigger that toggle, the `audio` tag that is playing inside that div suddenly pauses. I have no other audio related JS anywhere else in my code.

The div is initially hidden and the autoplay works as intended but pauses as soon as the toggle function is executed.

How do I stop the audio from pausing when I show/hide the div?

Comment: I think the reason is when the *toggle()* event fires, jQuery UI adds a wrapper and modifies the DOM. This modification might be causing reinit of `<audio>` tag pausing the audio. Also put in the correct `</div>` ending tag.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I remove the parameters from the `toggle` function so that its just `div.toggle()`, it works fine. How strange.